# Merge Lists into one list in R

Tags: r, dataframe, web-scraping

I'm trying to merge list with 10 lists into one data frame the data is scraped from amazon with reviews of different books showing with 10 rows and four columns in 10 different tables right now in the variable "output_list". Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

scrape_amazon <- function(ASIN, page_num){

url_reviews <- paste0("https://www.amazon.co.uk/product-reviews/",ASIN,"/?pageNumber=",page_num)

doc <- read_html(url_reviews) # Assign results to `doc`

# Review Title
doc %>% 
  html_nodes("[class='a-size-base a-link-normal review-title a-color-base review-title-content a- 
text-bold']") %>%
html_text() -> review_title

# Review Text
doc %>% 
   html_nodes("[class='a-size-base review-text review-text-content']") %>%
  html_text() -> review_text

 # Number of stars in review
 doc %>%
    html_nodes("[data-hook='review-star-rating']") %>%
    html_text() -> review_star

  # Return a tibble
  tibble(review_title,
      review_text,
      review_star,
     page = page_num) %>% return()
  }

  ASIN <- "0007477155" # Specify ASIN
  page_range <- 1:10 # Let's say we want to scrape pages 1 to 10

  # Create a table that scrambles page numbers using `sample()`
  # For randomising page reads!
  match_key <- tibble(n = page_range,
                key = sample(page_range,length(page_range)))

  lapply(page_range, function(i){
   j <- match_key[match_key$n==i,]$key

   message("Getting page ",i, " of ",length(page_range), "; Actual: page ",j) # Progress bar

    Sys.sleep(3) # Take a three second break

    if((i %% 3) == 0){ # After every three scrapes... take another two second break

    message("Taking a break...") # Prints a 'taking a break' message on your console

    Sys.sleep(2) # Take an additional two second break
    }
    scrape_amazon(ASIN = ASIN, page_num = j) # Scrape
   }) -> output_list


   class(output_list)
   length(output_list)

   output_list
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Your `html_nodes` call is not working for `review_title`. Since it's length 0, when you try to call `tibble`, it fails. I see that you borrowed this code from [here](https://martinctc.github.io/blog/vignette-scraping-amazon-reviews-in-r/).

Comment: yes the code is borrowed from this link. can you tackle the issue which is coming

Comment: What exactly is your question?  It would be helpful to know what you've tried, where, specifically, you've gotten stuck, and what you don't understand. You've only said 'any help would be appreciated'.

Comment: I want to merge lists into one data frame which are in output_list variable

Comment: Try `do.call(rbind, list_of_your_tables)`

Comment: thanks this helped alot